# SQL server 2005 developer edition install , named instance does not show up

Tags: sql-server, installation

i am attempting to install SQL server 2005 developer (eval) edition. I have installed under a user account, and have created a named instance called SQL. in SSMS, when attempting to connect to database engine, the named instance i created does not show up either at first or under the "Browse for more" option

Answer (score 0):

It won't show up by default and the function that browses doesn't work well for named instances. You just need to register the named instance manually and then connect with Object Explorer.

Comment: register the named instance in SSMS? where do you do that?

Comment: @user1138859 - View-Registered Servers - right-click - New Server Registration